# How can I determine the gender of Neon Tetras?

Tags: fish, gender-differentiation, tetra

In my aquarium are some [Neon tetra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_tetra).

[image: Neon Tetra]
(source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_tetra))

I'd like them to breed, but I don't know if they can because I can't determine their genders.

After careful observation, I can identify some females (they have a larger belly).  Are there characteristics to help me tell which is which?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other characteristics

- The male is slender and the blue line is straighter while The female is rounder producing a bent blue line.
- Mostly, the males are bigger than females

Also see : [How to Tell If a Neon Tetra Is a Male or Female?](http://www.ehow.com/how_8170439_tell-neon-tetra-male-female.html)

Comment: Generally I've heard that males are *smaller* than females. E.g http://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/paracheirodon-innesi/

Comment: @toxotes Really, I heard the opposite. E.g http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_tell_the_difference_between_male_and_female_neon_tetras#slide2

Answer (score 6):

Males do tend to be more slender and females a bit rounder, but honestly, with a large enough school, you'll probably end up with a mix of both sexes anyway. I like a school of at least a dozen. The fish seem to be more at ease in a larger group, and with more fish, you have a better chance of getting a mix of males and females.